# Using awk to combine lines and write csv file

Tags: bash, awk

If I have a file that looks like

```
Title: Title1
Author: Author1
Body: Body1.1
      Body1.2
      Body1.3

Title: Title2
Author: Author2
Body: Body2.1
      Body2.2
      Body2.3
```

and so on.

I want to output

```
"Title1", "Author1", 
"Body1.1
 Body1.2
 Body1.3"

"Title2", "Author2",
"Body2.1
 Body2.2
 Body2.3"
```

as a csv file. How should I do it?

Also, note that sometimes author's name might contains ',' so we want to make sure that everything is in string format

I am now trying to use awk to do the job for me by using while loop, but I am sure there should be an easier way to do this.

Comment: If you're not using `awk` for fun, I recommend you go for a more powerful language. In `python`, `ruby` or `javascript`, this would be trivial `=)`

Comment: How do you plan to represent multiline `B1` in CSV? double quotes, or backslash-escaped newline characters?

Comment: `cut -d: -f2 foo | grep -v '^$' | paste -d, - - -`

Comment: please give a better example of what  you mean for `B1 (with multiple lines)`, right now, it subject to several interpretations, AND as @kojiro rightly points out, what do you expect that multi-line output to look like in the `csv` version. Good luck!

Comment: @shelter I want to represent B1 as a string. For example, B1 could be 

 "with trembling waves
  Accepted the axe of the Roman law.
  O weep for the man! This world never saw
  One quicker a troublesome suit to decide"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the output that you want. Hopefully the comments make it clear what is going on.

```
$ cat script.awk    
BEGIN { FS="[:[:space:]]+" } # set field separator to one or more colons or space chars
/Title/ { t=$2 } # save title
/Author/{ printf "\"%s\", \"%s\",\n", t, $2 } # print title and author
/Body:/{ f=1; printf "\"%s", $2; next } # set f to true and print 1st body
!NF{ f=0; print "\"\n" } # empty line, set f to false
f{ printf "\n %s", $2 } # print body
END{ print "\"" } # print final quote
$ awk -f script.awk file
"Title1", "Author1",
"Body1.1
 Body1.2
 Body1.3"

"Title2", "Author2",
"Body2.1
 Body2.2
 Body2.3"
```

Comment: I really love this one. Just one more concern. What if there is no author name or title name, is there a way to print empty string?

Comment: Also, what if title and author name have space within the name ex. Conan Doyle. Then I think this code will just print the first column?

Comment: It would need some modification to handle those cases. If you come up with some test cases and the desired output, then maybe the script can be modified

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F' *: *' '$1=="Title"{t=$2;if (b) print b;b="";next}
  $1=="Author"{printf "\"%s\", \"%s\"\n", t, $2;next}
  NF==1||$1=="Body"{sub(/^ +/, "", $1); b=(!b)? $2: b ORS $1;next}
  END{print b}' file
"Title1", "Author1"
Body1.1
Body1.2
Body1.3
"Title2", "Author2"
Body2.1
Body2.2
Body2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the input data, this `gnu awk` (`gnu` due to `RS`) may work:

```
awk -vRS= '{print "\""$2"\", \""$4"\",\n\""$6"\n "$7"\n "$8"\"\n"}' t
"Title1", "Author1",
"Body1.1
 Body1.2
 Body1.3"

"Title2", "Author2",
"Body2.1
 Body2.2
 Body2.3"
```

By setting Record Selector to nothing, it will thread each block of data as one record, then we just take what field number we need.